# Unable to send sms through way2sms using java

Tags: java

My code is like below.I have downloaded jar file of way2sms.

```
     import com.way2sms.SMS;
     class MsgSender {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
     String Username="xxxxxxxxxx";
     String Password="xxxxxxxxxx";
     String Number="xxxxxxxxxx";
     String Message="Hi";
     String Proxy="";

     SMS smsClient=new SMS();
     smsClient.send( Username, Password, Number, Message,Proxy);
      }
     }
```

Below one is the link for jar

mediafire.com/download/ztwzzwmfmmz/way2sms-api-4.0.0.jar

I have given my credentials,But after running program it is showing as,

```
Jul 06, 2015 9:53:06 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Logging in ...
null
Login Failed..`.
```

Comment: Add a link to jar file to test

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/ztwzzwmfmmz/way2sms-api-4.0.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need admin rights to Access System or root node...

Comment: how to obtain it?I am using through my own system.They said to keep proxy String as empty string.

Comment: Just run your MsgSender  as admin.

Comment: Actually in warning, it is saying that could not able to create node Prefs,I have manually added that Prefs to Software\JavaSoft\.          Now it is not showing warning.I have debugged the application.There i am getting cookie as null in sms.class in jar .

Comment: First I assumed, that prefs node was created/accessed by sms-api.jar, but if you doing that, you should just Change the way you doing it. Usually you should make following: Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(getClass());

Comment: Ya i have checked username and password but ya as you said that node should not be created manually.K I will try thank you